# Can I run Octave by using Raspbian jessie lite os image on Raspberry pi b?

Tags: raspbian

Is complete raspbian jessie os image is needed to run octave on raspberry pi b?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question - are you considering different disk images, or are you wondering if there's a smaller disk image than Jessie, or something completely different? Can you add any more details to your question that might help to explain more clearly?

Comment: I intend to put the minimum(size and features) required OS image on a 4Gb SD card(formatted) to run a octave code on Raspberry pi b. As Raspbian jessie full image is 1.3 Gb and Raspbian jessie lite only 284 Mb, I wondered if it would make any difference if I chose lite image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge Raspbian Lite is entirely convertable to 'full' Raspbian with enough `apt-get`. It's just Raspbian without some of the pre-installed features. With that in mind, anything that works on one should work on the other, but may require some additional installations on your part.